C Preprocessor - pass through variable to sub macro
I am currently writing a simple cursor library in c for parsing fix structured strings.
For example, it allows to parse the following string into to previously defined variables as follows (github):
char *test_string = "27,19";
S_CCURSOR_HANDLER cursor = {0};
ret = ccursor_init(&cursor, test_string, strlen(test_string));

uint8_t value_a = 0;
uint8_t value_b = 0;

// parse int values
ret &= ccursor_read_u8(&cursor, &value_a);
ret &= ccursor_skip_char(&cursor, ',');
ret &= ccursor_read_u8(&cursor, &value_b);

// check if empty
ret &= ccursor_is_empty(&cursor);

This works fine, but to make the interface a little bit more convenient, I would like to also provide some macro based definition.
For example: CCURSOR_PARSER(macro_parser, "27,19", U8(value_a) U8(value_b));
My problem now is, that I am to stupid to get the macro logic right.
Currently, I have the following macro code:
#define U8_EVAL(_var, _cur)                                                    \
  uint8_t _var = 0;                                                            \
  _cur##_ret &= ccursor_read_u8(&_cur, &_var);

#define U8(_var) U8_EVAL(_var, _cur)

#define CCURSOR_PARSER(_cur, _str, _pattern)                                   \
  bool _cur##_ret = false;                                                     \
  S_CCURSOR_HANDLER _cur = {0};                                                \
  _cur##_ret = ccursor_init(&_cur, _str, strlen(_str));                        \
  _pattern

This does not compile, because it complains that _cur is the first use within the U8 to U8_EVAL macro expansion. My general question is actually, if I can somehow inject the value of _cur from the parent macro CCURSOR_PARSER into all the sub macros such as U8, U16, etc.
The simplest solution would be to extend U8 with the _cur (U8(_var, _cur)), but this would not make the user code nice; it would expand to CCURSOR_PARSER(macro_parser, "27,19", U8(value_a, macro_parser) U8(value_b, macro_parser)); what is not my goal.
Is there a way to pass through the _cur to all sub macros?

This looks like a perfect use-case for proper functions, not macros. Functions will improve the code greatly with type safety and maintainability. What is the reason you aren't using functions?

I disagree that the macro version you envision would be more convenient for anyone other than you, its author.  And maybe not even for you.  C programmers generally want to write in C, not in a custom, macro-defined mini-language particular to your package.

The interface looks perfect, I would only change S_CCURSOR_HANDLER to lowercase, and add robust error handling after each call. As for macro, it will only confuse things.

Thank you very much for the feedback.
Lundin: functions do not allow me to define variables on the fly. In addition, dealing with variable amount of arguments is possible but tricky in C.
JohnBollinger: I agree with you that the raw C code looks more understandable. But the MACRO would limit the boilerplate of initiate all variables. It's a thread off in my opinion.
KamilCuk: You are right, the uppercase struct name is a bad habit from my current work. Changed it to lowercase and I will add in the future a proper error handling.

I will close the ticket, because the interface of the library is fine enough. As ruled out by the comments above, the macro would only confuse the users and does not enhance readability.
